Laravel 11 not registering events and listeners automatically
I started a new project with Laravel 11.x, and I created 1 event and 1 listener through CLI sail artisan make:event UserResetedPassword and sail artisan make:listener SendEmailUserResetPassword --event=UserResetedPassword, then scripts succesfully created event and listener (code bellow).
I associate the event when a User is created:
 protected $dispatchesEvents = [
        'created' => UserResetedPassword::class
    ];

But my listener never has been called.
My app.php is unmodified.
When I register the events manually through AppServiceProvider.php, then the application recognize and associate the event/listener.
UserResetedPassword.php
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class UserResetedPassword {
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public function __construct(public readonly User $user) {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array<int, Channel>
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): array {
        return [
            new PrivateChannel('channel-name'),
        ];
    }
}


SendEmailUserResetPassword.php
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\UserResetedPassword;
use App\Services\Mail\SendEmailUserCreatedPasswordService;

class SendEmailUserResetPassword {
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     */
    public function __construct(private SendEmailUserCreatedPasswordService $service) {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     */
    public function handle(UserResetedPassword $event): void {
        $this->service->sendEmailUserCreatedPassword($event->user);
    }
}


output of sail artisan event:list
  Filament\Events\ServingFilament ..................................................................................................................  
  ⇂ Closure at: /vendor/filament/filament/src/FilamentServiceProvider.php:89  
  ⇂ Closure at: /vendor/filament/filament/src/FilamentServiceProvider.php:89  
  Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered ................................................................................................................  
  ⇂ Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification  
  Illuminate\Database\Events\QueryExecuted .........................................................................................................  
  ⇂ Spatie\LaravelIgnition\Recorders\QueryRecorder\QueryRecorder@record  
  Illuminate\Foundation\Events\LocaleUpdated .......................................................................................................  
  ⇂ Closure at: /vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Laravel/ServiceProvider.php:57  
  Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Events\RequestHandled .................................................................................................  
  ⇂ Closure at: /vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Features/SupportAutoInjectedAssets/SupportAutoInjectedAssets.php:24  
  Illuminate\Log\Events\MessageLogged ..............................................................................................................  
  ⇂ Spatie\LaravelIgnition\Recorders\LogRecorder\LogRecorder@record  
  Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobExceptionOccurred .....................................................................................................  
  ⇂ Spatie\LaravelIgnition\Recorders\JobRecorder\JobRecorder@record  
  Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobProcessed .............................................................................................................  
  ⇂ Closure at: /vendor/spatie/laravel-ignition/src/IgnitionServiceProvider.php:262  
  Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobProcessing ............................................................................................................  
  ⇂ Closure at: /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Context/ContextServiceProvider.php:38  
  ⇂ Closure at: /vendor/spatie/laravel-ignition/src/IgnitionServiceProvider.php:256  
  OwenIt\Auditing\Events\AuditCustom ...............................................................................................................  
  ⇂ OwenIt\Auditing\Listeners\RecordCustomAudit  
  OwenIt\Auditing\Events\DispatchAudit .............................................................................................................  
  ⇂ OwenIt\Auditing\Listeners\ProcessDispatchAudit (ShouldQueue)  


Already tried register events manually.
I expect Laravel recognizes events and listeners automatically.

what does artisan event:list show?

hello, I attached in question the output of sail artisan event:list

From your event: list command, there is no mapping between your event and listener. By including --event=UserResetedPassword into your command Laravel automatically resolves the mapping. But you can still try to add manually in the boot method of the ServiceProvider class. The code should look similar to this;
Event::listen(UserResetedPassword::class,SendEmailUserResetPassword::class);
For More https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/events
